# Выполнится ли хранимая функция в mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Подключаюсь к mongodb из nodejs посредством mongoose. В коллекции db.system.js имеется хранимая функция, которую я запускаю из nodejs. Она достаточно объемная, она апдейтит много данных и выполняется асинхронно неизвестное количество времени.  И вот если в монгусе я отключусь от монги, сама функция в ней продолжит отрабатывать, или тоже завершится?

**UPDATE:**

Действительно, никак. Я мог вытаскивать функцию таким образом:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var test = mongoose.model('System.js', new Schema({ "_id" : { type : String, default : "" }, "value" : { type : String, default : "" } }));
test.find( { '_id' : '_test' }, function( err, res ) {
        //
});
```

И почему-то подумал, что мог бы ее выполнить. Я ошибся. Хорошо, тогда по-другому. Допустим, я из терминала вызову функцию командой:

```
mongo testdb --eval "db.system.js.findOne({ _id : '_test' }).value()"
```

Функция выполняется. И если я оборву выполнение в терминале, функция прервется в mongodb? )

Comment: Покажите как вы её (функцию) используете.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian спасибо ) обновил вопрос